# no executable found matching command "dotnet-install"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code

This is on a mac / vscode setup.
I can't install anything from the CLI because of this error message.

How could I remedy to this ?
The command was:

```
dotnet install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook
```

Comment: `dotnet` CLI later removed that command. Make sure you use their stable releases (avoid preview builds if possible) and read its documentation carefully, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, even Microsoft Docs uses same command but there is a comment:

dotnet install no longer works. add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook to project.json and run "dotnet restore"

[Microsoft Docs Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) you should be able to try these.

Windows:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "&([scriptblock]::Create((Invoke-WebRequest -useb 'https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1'))) <additional install-script args>"
```

macOS/Linux:

```
curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin <additional install-script args>
```